# I am trying to make chat app api using DRF and web socket and i need to understand how run web socket server

Tags: django-rest-framework, websocket, django-channels

I am beginner with web socket. I have a project with accounts app for custom User model which stored in sqlite database and the authentcation method is JWT, and chat app for chat api which data stored in mongodb. also i use redis. Now i am not sure that my code is correct or not, and i need to know how run web socket server and make url for send chats.

```
here my models of chat app:
from djongo import models
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.core.validators import FileExtensionValidator
from django.utils.text import slugify

def validate_image_size(value):
    try:
        limit = 2 * 1024 * 1024 # e.g. 2MB
        if value.size > limit:
            raise ValidationError('File too large. Image should not exceed 2MB.')
    except AttributeError:
        raise ValidationError('Invalid value. Expected a file.')

def validate_image_format(value):
    try:
        valid_extensions = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif']
        FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=valid_extensions)(value)
    except ValidationError:
        raise ValidationError('Invalid file extension. Allowed extensions are: jpg, jpeg, png, gif.')


class Room(models.Model):
    room_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    room_slug = models.CharField(max_length=50, 
                                 unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.room_name
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not room_slug:
            room_slug = slugify(room_name)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    
     
class Chat(models.Model): 
    sender    = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    receiver  = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    message   = models.TextField()
    image     = models.FileField(upload_to='chat_images', 
                                  blank=True, 
                                  null=True,
                                  validators=[validate_image_format,
                                              validate_image_size])
    room_name = models.ForeignKey(Room,
                                  related_name='rooms', 
                                  on_delete=models.CASCADE)   

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'chat'

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Chat {self.id}"
```

asgi.py:

> import os
> import django
> from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
> from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
> from chat.routing import websocket_urlpatterns
> from django.conf import settings
>
> os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'settings')
>
> application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
> "http": get_asgi_application(),
> "websocket": URLRouter(
> websocket_urlpatterns
> ),
> })

consumers.py:

```
import json 
import jwt
from .models import Chat
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer
from django.conf import settings
from channels.db import database_sync_to_async
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from urllib.parse import parse_qs

User = get_user_model()

class ChatConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        # Authenticate the user using JWT token
        query_string = self.scope['query_string'].decode()
        token = parse_qs(query_string).get('token', [''])[0]
        if not token:
            await self.close()
        else:
            user = await self.get_user_from_token(token)
            if user is None:
                await self.close()
            else:
                self.user = user
                await self.accept()

    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        # Perform any cleanup tasks when the WebSocket connection is closed
        pass

    async def receive(self, text_data):
        # Handle incoming WebSocket messages
        try:
            data = json.loads(text_data)
            message = data['message']
            chat_id = data['chat_id']
            await self.save_message(chat_id, message)
            await self.send_message(chat_id, message)
        except (json.JSONDecodeError, KeyError):
            # Handle the case when the JSON data is empty or invalid
            # You can log an error message or take appropriate action here
            pass

    @database_sync_to_async
    def get_user_from_token(self, token):
        # Retrieve the user from the JWT token
        try:
            user_id = jwt.decode(token, settings.SECRET_KEY, algorithms=['HS256'])['user_id']
            return User.objects.get(id=user_id)
        except (jwt.DecodeError, User.DoesNotExist):
            return None

    @database_sync_to_async
    def save_message(self, chat_id, message):
        # Save the message to the Chat model
        chat = Chat.objects.get(id=chat_id)
        chat.messages.create(sender=self.user, content=message)

    async def send_message(self, chat_id, message):
        # Send the message to all connected clients in the chat room
        await self.channel_layer.group_send(
            f'chat_{chat_id}',
            {
                'type': 'chat_message',
                'message': message,
                'sender': self.user.username
            }
        )

    async def chat_message(self, event):
        # Receive the message from the group and send it to the WebSocket
        message = event['message']
        sender = event['sender']
        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'message': message,
            'sender': sender
        }))
```

routing.py:

> from django.urls import path
> from .consumers import ChatConsumer
> from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
> from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
>
> websocket_urlpatterns = [
> path('ws/chat/', ChatConsumer.as_asgi()),
> ]
>
> application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
> 'websocket': AuthMiddlewareStack(
> URLRouter(
> websocket_urlpatterns
> )
> ),
> })

Is my code is correct? and how run socket server without front-end?